# UITableviewCell not cleaning data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hello Guys am working in iOS App, in which am showing users data on a `UITableview`. For the first user its working fine but when i clicked like `UIbutton` and want to show the next user data the `UITableviewCell` not cleaning the previous user data, even though am assigning empty string to each label before to display next user data. My code is here

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    UILabel *headLablel,*textLabel,*subLabel,*sharedActLbl;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }


    headLablel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    headLablel.tag=11;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:headLablel];
    textLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    textLabel.tag=12;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];
    subLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    subLabel.tag=13;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:subLabel];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Don't add subview, better use a custom `UITableViewCell`, or manually clean it (but that's quite ugly in my opinion). `UITableVIewCell` are **reused**.

Comment: if your are add components to cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need remove this components every time and re build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding new subviews (`headLablel`, `textLabel`, `subLabel`), each time cell is dequeued. This is wrong, because when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method, it returns a cell which was already displayed. So you add new subviews over and over again, that's why old data remains.

**I recommend you to subclass `UITableViewCell`.**

If you don't want, you can fix your code like this:

```
for (UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}

headLablel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
headLablel.tag=11;
[cell.contentView addSubview:headLablel];
textLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
textLabel.tag=12;
[cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];
subLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
subLabel.tag=13;
[cell.contentView addSubview:subLabel];
```

This will be inefficient because you will create new labels each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add your subviews when you create a custom cell class,in `initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)reuseIdentifier` .
If you want to generate cells with different subviews, you can also set different cell styles,in this way, it can improve your app's performance when the tableView reuses cells.Adding subviews when the tableView dequeues cells might cause unexpected problems.

Happy Programming!

Answer (score 0):

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

```
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}
else{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
[cell.contentView clearsContextBeforeDrawing];
```

---

in Cell for row creation of UITableViewCell code replace with my code and check it's work.. i have worked with mannual release if you are not then release autorelease with it's bracket..